# How do I convert <img> tags in markdown cells when exporting in Jupyter?

Tags: html, image, markdown, jupyter, nbconvert

I've got a large report-like notebook which has got many images. Instead of using the `![title](link)` syntax, I've had to use `<img src="link" align="right" width=100>` instead, so I have better control on them.

While this works inside the notebook in Jupyter Server, the **inline `<img>` tags get rendered verbatim, instead of showing up as images**.

I figure the problem resides with the `nbconvert` module which handles the conversion, but it seems as though a [similar issue has already been resolved](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/328).

My links were originally linking directly to `http://` links, but I've pulled them all locally, and am still getting verbatim HTML code instead of images.

---

[image: In Jupyter vs rendered HTML]

---

- Jupyter version: `4.2.1`
- nbconvert version: `5.2.1`
- Python: `3.6.1`
- Distribution: Anaconda
- Platform: Windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/328#issuecomment-317524675) this may be related to how mistune (which nbconvert uses) parses html attributes. What version of mistune do you have?

If you have `mistune` 0.7.3 you will run into the following:

```
In [1]: import mistune

In [2]: mistune.markdown('\n <img src="link" align="right" widt
   ...: h=100>  \n', escape=False)
Out[2]: '<p>&lt;img src="link" align="right" width=100&gt;</p>\n'

In [3]: mistune.markdown('\n <img src="link" align="right" widt
   ...: h="100">  \n', escape=False)
Out[3]: '<p><img src="link" align="right" width="100"></p>\n'

In [4]: mistune.__version__
Out[4]: '0.7.3'
```

Whereas 0.7.4 provides:

```
In [1]: import mistune

In [2]: mistune.markdown('\n <img src="link" align="right" widt
   ...: h=100>  \n', escape=False)
Out[2]: '<p><img src="link" align="right" width=100></p>\n'

In [3]: mistune.markdown('\n <img src="link" align="right" widt
   ...: h="100">  \n', escape=False)
Out[3]: '<p><img src="link" align="right" width="100"></p>\n'

In [4]: mistune.__version__
Out[4]: '0.7.4'
```

If you add quotes to your html attributes – e.g., `<img src="link" align="right" width="100">` – that may fix the problem.

Comment: edited the answer to explain how mistune was probably the source of the error

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading mistune solves the problem for me.

```
conda install mistune=0.7.2
```